# AddEventListener for an array element is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to receive the input and if it has some mistakes regarding the pre-typed text I want to (1) highlight the mistakes with the red color and (2) on hover show the correct version of the words.

I've managed to do the first part but I'm struggling with the second idea.

Here is my code:

```js
let string = "The quick brown fox jumps over lazy the lazy dog";
let input = document.querySelector(".js-textarea");

let showRight = function(word) {
  let rightWord = document.querySelector(".right-word");
  rightWord.classList.remove("none");
  rightWord.innerText = word;
}

let checkValue = function() {
  let receivedValue = input.value.split(/(\s+)/).filter( e => e.trim().length > 0);
  let splitString = string.split(/(\s+)/).filter( e => e.trim().length > 0);
  for (let i = 0; i < receivedValue.length; i++) {
    if (receivedValue[i] !== splitString[i]) {
      receivedValue[i] = '<span class="error related">'+receivedValue[i]+'</span>';
      receivedValue[i].addEventListener('mouseover', showRight(splitString[i]));
    }
  }
  let output = receivedValue.join(" ");
  let correctedText = document.querySelector(".text");
  correctedText.innerHTML = output;
}

input.addEventListener("change",checkValue);
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

.matches {
   color: black
}

.related {
  position: related;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.right-word {
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea-block">
  <textarea class="js-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
<span class="text"></span>
<span class="absolute none right-word"></span>

<div style="display:none">
  <span class="errorbox" style="color:red"></span>
</div>
```

I don't really understand why it shows me that the addEventListener part is not a function. I assume it has to do something with the array, but I don't really see the problem.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Short answer is that `receivedValue[i]` is just a string even though it is a string of html. It is  not a dom element that you can use `addEventListener` to until that string gets inserted into the dom

Comment: A simple array has no `addEventListener` property, its a prop for the DOM element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuplrit statements:-

```
  receivedValue[i] = '<span class="error related">'+receivedValue[i]+'</span>';
  receivedValue[i].addEventListener('mouseover', showRight(splitString[i]));
```

`receivedValue[i]` is being set to a string. And you're calling `addEventListener` on a string which is invalid. `addEventListener` should be called on a DOM element.

Comment: thanks for your response, what's the best way to do it then?